# How to import data into specific column of an existing dataset and save as new dataset?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, openpyxl

As i continue my project on python web scraping to excel, I manage to extract the information I wanted and put it in  a fresh excel file. For the next step, instead of generating on a new sheet, I would like to put each of my data lists into a different column of an existing dataset.

Here's my code for the first step of collating all the details I need from the website and put in it in a data frame

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


path = "C:\\Users\\ChloeChew\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

website_list = ["https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-sg/product-support/servicetag/0-eDBNTlVQeS9UV2FyMmpDK3ZqUWdOdz090/overview",
                "https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-sg/product-support/servicetag/0-WldhUmxVOU9UZGxhSkVQQWZMMEo1UT090/overview",
                "https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-sg/product-support/servicetag/0-ZUQwbW14d28xZHZBYTZWNDdHVy80Zz090/overview",
                "https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-sg/product-support/servicetag/0-NGUxWVVCWkxFZGFxUTdYTTlZM3dsdz090/overview"]

#data = []
servicetag_list = []
expiry_list = []

for website in website_list:
    driver.get(website)
    # PARSE THE WEBSITE
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    #driver.save_screenshot('./save_screenshot_method.png')  # Capture the screen
    frame = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="site-wrapper"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div')

    for datas in frame:
        serial_number=(datas.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='service-tag mb-0 d-none d-lg-block']").text[13:])
        expiry_date=(datas.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='warrantyExpiringLabel mb-0 ml-1 mr-1']").text)
        #data.append({'Service Tag': serial_number,'Expiry Date': expiry_date})
        servicetag_list.append({'Service Tag': serial_number})
        expiry_list.append({'Expiry Date': expiry_date})


#df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print(df)
```

As im still quite new python, i believe that i have to seperate "expirydate" and "serial_number" into a different list [] since they will placed in a seperate index instead of side by side.

So i used pandas to read the old file and then insert new

```
oldfile = "C:\\Users\\ChloeChew\\PycharmProjects\\scrapping\\automation.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(oldfile)
df.insert(8, 'servicetag',servicetag_list)
df.insert(11, 'date',expiry_list)

df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ChloeChew\\PycharmProjects\\scrapping\\newfile.xlsx")
```

The error i faced: ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (5)

I've tried several methods, and the error i faced is  either "raise valueerror( cannot convert 0 r to excel .format(value))" or the "Length of values (4) does not match length of index (5)"
My [desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg4Fl.png) is to be able to put all the elements I've scrapped, into their respective column in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.insert`, you can try with `.loc` :

```py
example = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2, 3],
                        2: ["a", "b", "c"]})

service_tag_list = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
example.loc[:, 'service_tag'] = service_tag_list
print(example)
```

```
0  2 service_tag
0  1  a          ab
1  2  b          cd
2  3  c          ef
```

However it will only work if `service_tag_list` has the same length as `example` has rows. Which seems to be one of the problems here. Indeed, you said : "Length of values (4) does not match length of index (5)". Reading at your code, `service_tag_list` seems to be of length 4 and I assume `df`has 5 rows. For instance the following code will produce the same error :

```py
example = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2, 3],
                        2: ["a", "b", "c"]})

service_tag_list = ["ab", "cd"]
example.loc[:, 'service_tag'] = service_tag_list
print(example)
```

```
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3)
```

Without any more details about your errors or even a minimal reproducible example, I can't help you more.